# I made an expand button in html which changes icon and shows content (and reverses it) but media query works on second time (not first)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$('#click1').click(function () {
    var media = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 900px)")
    var media2 = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 901px)")
    if($(this).text() == 'unfold_more')
         $(this).text('unfold_less');
    else
        $(this).text( 'unfold_more');
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
    
    console.log("before:", x.style.display)
    
  if (x.style.display === "none" && media.matches) {
    x.style.display = "grid";
  } else if (x.style.display === "grid" && media.matches) {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else if (x.style.display === "flex") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }  else {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  }

    console.log("after:", x.style.display)
        
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tourney&effect=emboss');
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.title {
  padding-left: 5.5%;
  font-family: 'Tourney', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
}

.category {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5%;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-table;
}

.line {
  height: 3px;
  border: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #5335cf 0%, #de005e 25%, #f66e48 50%, #de005e 75%, #5335cf 100%);
  background-size: 400%;
  animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    background-position: 400%;
  }
  .line2 {
    height: 3px;
    border: 0;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 19%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
    background-size: 400%;
    animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
    align-self: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: -15px;
    width: 80%;
  }
  .hot {
    filter: invert();
  }
  .hyp {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: whitesmoke;
  }
}

h2 {
  color: #3696dc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px
}

.container {
  width: 82%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.columns {
  margin: 25px 15px 25px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  flex-basis: 33%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #00d4ff;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.card2 {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #00d4ff;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover {
  border: 3px solid #00d4ff;
  cursor: crosshair;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.card2:hover {
  border: 3px solid #00d4ff;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contain {
  display: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.card:hover .contain {
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.card2:hover .contain {
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.para {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

#click1 {
  position: unset;
  margin-right: 10%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

#click2 {
  position: unset;
  margin-right: 10%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

#click3 {
  position: unset;
  margin-right: 10%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

#click4 {
  position: unset;
  margin-right: 10%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

#myDIV1 {
  display: none;
}

#myDIV2 {
  display: none;
}

#myDIV3 {
  display: none;
}

#myDIV4 {
  display: none;
}

#page {
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .title {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }
  .card {
    border: 1px solid #00d4ff;
  }
  .card2 {
    border: 1px solid #00d4ff;
  }
  .card:hover {
    border: 2px solid #00d4ff;
  }
  .card2:hover {
    border: 2px solid #00d4ff;
  }
  .insta {
    padding-right: 1%;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
  }
  .category {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .hot {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  }
  .contain {
    font-size: 12px;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  }
  #click1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  #click2 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  #click3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  #click4 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  #myDIV1 {
    display: none;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  }
  #myDIV2 {
    display: none;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  }
  #myDIV3 {
    display: none;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  }
  #myDIV4 {
    display: none;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .qr {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>PixelByte</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="Cube_1.png">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/4.0.0/iconfont/material-icons.min.css">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1935d064dd.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="script.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightslider.js">
  </script>

</head>

<body id="page">
  <div class="content">
    <header>
      <div class="title">
        <a href="index.html" class="hyp">
          <h1 class="title"><b>PIXELBYTE</b></h1>
        </a>

      </div>
    </header>
    <hr class="line" width="80%" />
    <! –– HOT AND TRENDING ––>
    <p class="category"><img src="fire.png" alt="hot" width="27px" height="27px" class="hot" id="hot"> Hot and Trending </p><span class="material-icons" id="click1">unfold_more</span>
    <hr class="line2" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="columns">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_zaingfx/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="MicroSHIBA/Micro Shiba-1.png.png" alt="MicroSHIBA" width="100%" height="100%">
            <p class="contain">
              Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="columns">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_zaingfx/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="DOGELON/Dogelon Mars-1.png.png" alt="DOGELON Mars" width="100%" height="100%">
            <p class="contain">
              Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="columns">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_zaingfx/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="Baby EverDoge/Baby Everdoge-1.png (6).png" alt="Baby Everdoge" width="100%" height="100%">
            <p class="contain">
              Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="columns">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_zaingfx/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="Ghoul-1.png.png" alt="Ghoul" width="100%" height="100%">
            <p class="contain">
              Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="myDIV1">
      <div class="columns">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_zaingfx/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="MicroSHIBA/Micro Shiba-1.png.png" alt="MicroSHIBA" width="100%" height="100%">
            <p class="contain">
              Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="columns">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_zaingfx/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="DOGELON/Dogelon Mars-1.png.png" alt="DOGELON Mars" width="100%" height="100%">
            <p class="contain">
              Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="columns">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_zaingfx/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="Baby EverDoge/Baby Everdoge-1.png (6).png" alt="Baby Everdoge" width="100%" height="100%">
            <p class="contain">
              Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="columns">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_zaingfx/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="Ghoul-1.png.png" alt="Ghoul" width="100%" height="100%">
            <p class="contain">
              Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What I want it to do is display flex styled div on big screens and grid styled div on smaller ones. It works but on toggling the button the second time. The first time I click the button, it shows flex type div.

`x.style.display` in the css is `display: none`

```js
var media = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 900px)")

$('#click1').click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'unfold_more')
    $(this).text('unfold_less');
  else
    $(this).text('unfold_more');
    
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
  if (x.style.display === "flex") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else if (x.style.display === "flex") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else if (x.style.display === "grid" && media.matches) {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else if (x.style.display === "none" && media.matches) {
    x.style.display = "grid";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  }
```

Comment: Your `if` conditions are a mess, why are you keeping duplicate conditions

Comment: I am a newbie to JS. If you can optimize it for me, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Would yo not want your `var media = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 900px)")` *inside* the `if`?   Not sure if it's relevant to the question as you don't mention resizing.

Comment: What *exactly* is the value of `x.style.display` when you first call it?  And the second, third?  A [quick fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtjd2u58/) shows it's "blank", but you may have other css etc.  So first time it doesn't use `media.matches` and defaults to final 'else' (from what's provided, ideally please provide a stack snippet ([edit] and click `[<>]`) which *demonstrates* the issue).

Comment: x.style.display in the css is display: none

Comment: You're saying `x.style.display === "display: none"`? - well that's not good (and doesn't match any of your `if`s)

Comment: I've just edited my JS with the var in the function and the unneccesary if statement removed. It still doesn't seem to work (It is showing flex in screens under 900px.)

Comment: Thanks for adding a snippet, however, please read [mcve] - you should only include the relevant code - it was overly difficult to find the `<span id=click1>`.

Comment: Back to my previous question: What is the value of `x.style.display` - adding a console.log and running your snippet outputs as `''` - ie your code goes to the last `else` and makes it `flex`.

Comment: *Step* through your code using the browser debugger and check each `if` statement.

Comment: Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: Add `if (x.style.display === "") x.style.display = ...whatever you want it to be...`